# Can someone explain the unusually high minimum supply current of ESP32-WROOM-32E?

Tags: esp32, power-consumption

I had chosen the FireBeetle 2 ESP32-E board for a future project.  I started looking at the power consumption details  and I came across this [posting](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=20644).  It's about some mysterious startup current draw when Bluetooth BLE is initialized (400-700 mA for 30 ms).  I figured the software was at fault (turned something on by mistake).  But, in the posting they pretty much told him the spec says 500 mA current min for powering it (I found it in the esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue datasheet).  That seems high to me.

Now, I'm not an electrical engineer (I was a software/firmware engineer), but it seems odd to have such a high value for minimum current on such a microprocessor since it really depends on what clocks you have turned on.  So, either I'm wrong and this is typical, or maybe this chip does odd stuff when the radio subsystem clock(s) are turned on.  Can someone offer any insight or explanation?  Right now, I'm assuming there is no workaround and will choose another board/processor that has more modest current requirements.

Comment: The esp32 has a reasonably powerful rf output. My guess it needs to do some calibration first up. If you want BLE and low power, then chose a BLE only part. For the esp32, BLE is just icing on the cake as it is predominantly a WiFi device with the power consumption that it entails.

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting--do you think it's something to do with the frequency synthesis, or something else (just curious)?  As for choosing another device, I already had several ones that would work.  It's just this one had such a low price, I HAD to look into it :).